# Is there a desktop / web app to manage Android contact linking?

Tags: contacts

Contacts on my Android phone come from different sources (Google account, Facebook, Skype, Windows Live etc.) and I can link them manually using the People app or how it's called. The user interface is not too bad but still, if there was a desktop / web application for this I think I would prefer that. Is there any?

Things I've tried and that *don't* support this:

- Google Contacts (only supports Google account contacts, not Skype, Facebook etc.)
- Samsung Kies
- Remote Web Desktop
- Airdroid

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, there is no sort of cloud service that will handle this for you.  Since the *combination* of contacts from the various apps you have installed only exists on your phone, no one of the services you use will be able to make global changes to your contacts.

This is not to say that it's technically impossible to do what you're asking:  Since it's possible to write an app to make changes to contacts, and since it's possible to write an app that could act as a web server, there's nothing preventing a program from providing a web-interface to the contacts on a phone.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned Remote Web Desktop, Airdroid and Samsung Kies. However, in none of these I have found the linking functionality, unfortunately. Maybe there's some other app that can do that?

Comment: Whoops. Sorry about that. Removed the app recommendation. As for what you're asking, its completely possible.  Happy searching and if you can't find it, sounds like a great app idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a desktop/web app that will do this. However, I did this a few months ago by downloading a third-party contacts app (for Android, not desktop/web), using its (much smarter) merge function, and then uninstalling the app. I can't remember for sure, but I think the app I used was either [Contacts by Contapps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contapps.android) or [GO Contacts EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbapps.contactpro). There's also [Contact Analyzer 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrew.contactanalyzer2), but there are some reports of it deleting all contacts instead of merging!